# AngularJS and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I am trying to dynamically change my GA tracking ID (UA-XXXXXXX-X) depending on which environment the page is being viewed on but I can't seem to find a truly "angular" way to do it. I am using Angulartics but I can't get the base GA code to run which is needed before Angulartics can do anything. If I just put the GA code at the bottom of the page it works as expected but that isn't very Angular like and it still does not allow me to dynamically set the GA ID.

I have tried creating a directive but the tracking code doesn't seem to be run when put inside a directive's controller. I have created a controller that gets the environment from a rest call and then assigns a GA code based on the environment returned but when I run the directive it runs to early and the GA code doesn't fire or it fires while the tracking ID is still undefined. I also tried putting the GA code into the directives template but for some reason the code doesn't fire at all when placed inside script tags inside the ngAnalytics.html template even though i can see it is being correctly added to the page once the dom is loaded. I am new to angular so I know there is a solution but I am not seeing it. My directive is below:

```
angular.module('ngAnalytics', [])
.directive('ngAnalytics', function( servicesSrvc) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/ngAnalytics.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.trackingID;
            $scope.getEnvDetails = function() {
                var currentEnv = servicesSrvc.getEnv();
                var env;
                currentEnv.then(function(data) {
                    env = JSON.stringify(data.environment);
                    switch(env)
                {
                    case 'local':
                        $scope.trackingID = 'disabled'; // DEV
                        break;
                    case 'dev':
                        $scope.trackingID = 'UA-XXX-X'; // DEV
                        break;
                    ...
                        $scope.trackingID = 'UA-XXX-X'; // Default to dev
                }
                (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
                ga('create', $scope.trackingID, { 'cookieDomain': 'none' }); // For localhost testing
                //ga('create', $scope.trackingID, 'test.com'); // For dev, qa, prod etc...
                //ga('send', 'pageview'); // MUST BE DISABLED when using Angulartics
            });
        }

    }],
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {

    }
}
});
```

Comment: Will this vary per page, or per deployment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your issue. It sounds like a general problem of directive architecture. Is something like this what you're looking for? [**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/uFeHUjO/1/edit)

```
<div analytics="trackingId"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  //set this however you want, the directive doesn't care - or you can move this into the directive if you want
  //$scope.trackingId = 'UA-XXX-X';
  $scope.trackingId = 'disabled';
});

app.directive('analytics', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      id: '=analytics'
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      scope.$watch('id', function(newId, oldId) {
        if (newId) {
          console.log(newId);
          ga('create', scope.id, { 'cookieDomain': 'none' });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The important part here is:

```
scope.$watch('id', function(newId, oldId) {
  if (newId) {
    ga('create', scope.id, { 'cookieDomain': 'none' });
  }
});
```

which is saying to run the function only if there is a value for `scope.id` and the function will run again if the value is set or changed. I'm not sure what you're doing with `servicesSrvc`, but you could use that service to set `scope.id` from the controller or in the directive itself, either way, and if you've already setup the `$watch`, the function will run when you determine the value for `scope.id`. My answer is based on your comment that the function would run when the value was undefined. This is how you avoid that.

#### Update

Since you're still having issues understand the process, I have created another demo with some `console.log`s to guide you. **[Demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/uFeHUjO/4/edit)**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('myService', function($q, $timeout) {
  var myService = {
    getId: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      console.log('getting id');
      $timeout(function() {
        //deferred.resolve('UA-XXX-X');
        deferred.resolve('disabled');
      }, 2000);

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});

app.directive('analytics', function(myService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      var id;
      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return id; 
        }, 
        function(newId, oldId) {
          if (newId) {
            console.log('watch is calling function');
            ga('create', newId, { 'cookieDomain': 'none' });
          }
        }
      );

      myService.getId().then(function(response) {
        id = response;
        console.log('id set to ' +response);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I am trying your approach but it is still failing and I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I copied your above code verbatim and inserted it into my app, just changing the app name. It runs and an alert outside of the watch statement executes so i know the directive is loaded and running but the $watch function never runs with a updated value, it just runs when the directive in initialized. What is supposed to trigger the change of the trackingID value so that the $watch statement runs with the updated value? Right now I see the $watch runs once but the scope.id is still undefined when it does.

Comment: @RAC I can't say for sure...but it sounds like you don't understand a lot of what Angular is doing in general. In my example, I am setting the value in the controller "myCtrl", so you would need `ng-controller` on an element in your html. As I said, you could get the value to the directive many ways. This is probably the most dynamic, so I did it that way (just to give the most informative demonstration).

Comment: I am starting to think it isn't an Angular Issue more a google Analytics issue. I am injecting the GA code 2 seconds after the page is loaded just as a test and it says it is registering the tracker but the tracking code is not firing.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it did clear things up for me and also confirmed that my issue isn't actually with the directive but with GA and using Angulartics together. Apparently my GA code has always been firing with the correct ID but the pageview was not because Angulartics says you need to leave out [ga('send', 'pageview');] which is supposed to fire your page view. Though with that commented out I don't get a pageview sent to GA at all meaning the problem is with Angulartics. Your answer is a more efficient way to write the code I initially wrote so thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to call `ga('send', 'pageview')` also or Analitycs will track nothing.